# Trouble Importing PHP Class

Tags: php, class, oop

I am working with an API that has a "supported" library written by a third party.

I've done as the instructions say and feel I am very close to getting it working as it should however no matter what I try, (renaming, absolute paths, aggregated file paths, etc.) I'm getting the same error.

*I have an API key. This is not the issue

The error arises in this block:

```
define('API_KEY', ''); // //-- Insert your API key 
define('PHP_SELF', htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

require_once("FFN.class.php");

$ffn = new FFN(API_KEY); //where actual error is thrown

if (!API_KEY) {
        echo 'You did not set the API_KEY for your application. This is required.';
        exit;
}
```

And states:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FFN' not found in /st/3/g/public_html/path/nerdapi.php on line 16
```

The actual error is thrown on `$ffn = new FFN(API_KEY);`

If anyone can spot my probably very obvious error, I'd really appreciate it.

Here is the site where I got the 3rd party code for the API's

https://github.com/philip/FantasyNerdAPI

Comment: Well, is the path right or not?

Comment: @DamienPirsy yes, the path should be correct. I used the linux command  readlink to find the exact file path and it matches. I've tried supplying that into the `requireonce` as well but the same error occurred

Comment: I test your code. I didn't got such error. make sure the file having above code and FFN.class.php are in same folder

Comment: either the path of FFN.class.php is wrong OR the class name. Please check in FFN.class.php

Answer (score 0):

i download the file, and put up these file:

FFN.class.php

sdk.php

on htdocs/a and accessing localhost/a/sdk.php

result was : You did not set the API_KEY for your application. This is required.

well, i didnt put the key.

Comment: I have an api key and it's supplied

Comment: did u try what i do?
it seems no error on my machine, could you tell us what os/machine, php version, etc. you use.